# Attempting to run an embedded Ktor HTTP Server on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

I'm trying to embed Ktor in an Android Service in order to check remotely some assets on an app at some point.

I'm following the code in this [tutorial](https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-backend-yes-its-possible-953388acffc3)

I get this error when I attempt to access the link for example on "192.168.2.105:7070":

```
04-20 14:50:58.523 29389-29389 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mypackage.fetchingservice, PID: 29389
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:io.ktor.application.ApplicationEvents$subscribe$1
        at io.ktor.application.ApplicationEvents.subscribe(ApplicationEvents.kt:18)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.BaseApplicationEngine.<init>(BaseApplicationEngine.kt:29)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.BaseApplicationEngine.<init>(BaseApplicationEngine.kt:15)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.<init>(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:16)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:10)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:8)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:50)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:40)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer$default(EmbeddedServer.kt:27)
        at com.hirschandmann.magickservice.KtorFetchService.onCreate(KtorFetchService.kt:30)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2761)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1386)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:935)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:730)
```

Here's the code. Service is registered in the manifest and I launch it from adb using: 
`adb shell am startservice com.mypackage.service/.KtorFetchService`

```
class KtorFetchService : Service() {
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    private val HTTP_PORT = 7070
    override fun onCreate() {
        embeddedServer(Netty, HTTP_PORT) {
            routing {
                get("/") {
                    call.respondText("My Example Fetch", ContentType.Text.Html)
                }
            }
        }.start(wait = true)
        super.onCreate()
    }
}
```

Here's the module gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hirschandmann.magickservice"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/*'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" }
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx" }
}

configurations {
    ktlint
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    // AutoValue
    compileOnly "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2"

    // ktlint
    ktlint "com.github.shyiko:ktlint:0.15.0"

    implementation'com.github.hkk595:Resizer:v1.5'
    implementation'com.jrummyapps:android-shell:1.0.1'
    implementation'org.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:2.3.1'
    implementation"io.ktor:ktor:$ktor_version" // ktor dependency
    implementation"io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version"

}
task ktlint(type: JavaExec, group: "verification") {
    description = "Check Kotlin code style."
    classpath = configurations.ktlint
    main = "com.github.shyiko.ktlint.Main"
    args "src/**/*.kt"
    //args "--reporter=checkstyle,output=${buildDir}/ktlint.xml"
}
check.dependsOn ktlint

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Here's the project's gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.40'
    ext.ktor_version = '0.9.1'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt" version "1.0.0.RC6-3"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

detekt {
    version = "1.0.0.RC6-3"
    profile("main") {
        input = "$projectDir/app/src/main/java"
        config = "$projectDir/default-detekt-config.yml"
        filters = ".*test.*,.*/resources/.*,.*/tmp/.*"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The device is an Odroid C2 with Android 5.1.1 (API 22)
I'm using Android studio 3.1 and JRE 1.8 running on a MacOS 10.13.3.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the problem in a new project. But was not able to reproduce your problem that initially looked like a proguard issue. I have uploaded a working project here for reference:

https://github.com/soywiz/android-ktor-example

If it doesn't work for you, please upload the your complete project reproducing the problem somewhere and I will try to help you.

Comment: Your code works on my phone on Android 7. So does my initial code. It doesn't run though on the Odroid C2 with Android 5.1.

Comment: I tried to embed Ktor in an Android app as well. Running on an Android 5.0 Lollipop, API 21 (either real device or emulator) leads to exactly the mentioned error in the question. Running the same code in Android 7, API 24 (emulator) it is working well.

Comment: I ended up using NanoHttpd as the target devices use API 22

Comment: Do you have any sample project that using NanoHttp ? @iulisiio Because i found there is [restlet](https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/user-guide/2.3/editions/android/overview) that is looks like the competitor for nanohttp but i'm still blind to decide.

Comment: @Rhony If I were to work on the same project again I would use [sparkjava](http://sparkjava.com/). Not sure how embedabble it is in Android, but it's certainly quick to set things up and will work very smoothly with Kotlin lambdas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is caused by the following line in ktor [ApplicationEvents.kt:18](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/6e01d44ce302fecab419377d494cd3554eabedbc/ktor-server/ktor-server-core/src/io/ktor/application/ApplicationEvents.kt#L18)

```
handlers.computeIfAbsent(definition) { LockFreeLinkedListHead() }.addLast(registration)
```

This causes it to fail as far as `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent` and `java.util.function.Function` has been initially introduced in API level 24 ([proof](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/function/Function)).

Note that ktor server was never intended to run on android and originally targeted to servers with JDK8

Answer (score 5):

I've been running a Netty-based Ktor server on Android 5+ for a while, and I've created this minimal repo to demo it: https://github.com/gnarea/minimal-ktor-server-android